# Loop array until matches the value of the item clicked

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I'm trying to loop through an array until it matches the value of the object that is clicked.

When the object is created the text input box shares it's value with the object and the array. I would like to be able to loop through the array until there is a match, then find the index, after that pass the index value to a variable to be used. From there remove the object that is clicked from the webpage and the array.

Additional details are that there is an input box with a button. The user enters a line of information into the input box and selects a button to appendChild it to the list. The object created is a div with the input value as the paragraph with a span element with an X which is supposed to remove the object when clicked.

**Here is the HTML Code being used**

```
<div id="outerDiv">
    <div id="taskList">

    </div>
</div>
```

**Here is the code to create the object.**

```
var magicArray = [];

function makeOutline() {

    var textValue = document.getElementById("inputBox").value;


    if (textValue == "" || textValue == null){
        alert("Please enter a item you want to add to the to-do list");
    } else {


    var inputField = document.getElementById("taskList");
    var inputText = document.createTextNode(textValue);

    var mainHeading = document.createElement("p");
    mainHeading.setAttribute("class", "outlineBorder");

    var spanText = document.createTextNode("x");
    var spanBox = document.createElement("span");
    spanBox.setAttribute("class", "close");
    spanBox.setAttribute("onclick", "removeMe()");


    var outlineList = document.createElement("div");
    outlineList.setAttribute("value", textValue);


    spanBox.appendChild(spanText);
    mainHeading.appendChild(inputText);
    mainHeading.appendChild(spanBox);
    outlineList.appendChild(mainHeading);
    inputField.appendChild(outlineList);

    magicArray[magicArray.length] = textValue;

    document.getElementById("inputBox").value = "";

    }
}
```

Here is the code to remove the item. 
I am able to have it set to a static number and work every time; however, 
struggling to find a dynamic solution since there can be multiple objects.

```
function removeMe() {

        var removeList = document.getElementById("taskList");
        removeList.removeChild(removeList.childNodes[1];

}
```

Here is a screenshot of the family tree structure
[image]

Comment: `Array.prototype.indexOf()` can be used to search an array for a value.

Comment: FYI, `magicArray[magicArray.length] = textValue` is usually written as `magicArray.push(textValue)`

Comment: Modern JavaScript flavors have [`Array.prototype.findIndex()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) which takes a function if you need more control over the matching.

Comment: These are great suggestions on the array part. I'm wondering how the code would look to get the value of the object clicked? @HereticMonkey

Comment: Considering the object clicked is a `span`, and `span` elements do not have a value, I don't really understand the question. You've got a reference to an element with an id of inputBox that is not in your HTML. Please [edit] your question to include a [mre]. You can probably use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to produce a runnable example.

Comment: @HereticMonkey The span element is used to hold the X that is clicked to delete the object. It runs the removeMe function when clicked.

Comment: I think it would be good to distinguish between what is actually getting clicked (a DOM object) and the abstract JavaScript object that you're associating the DOM objects to. I don't know your domain, but based on the names of your elements, you have a list of tasks, so the "object" you want to retrieve is a task object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can use `this` to get the element. [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Event_handlers):

> When the event handler is invoked, the this keyword inside the handler is set to the DOM element on which the handler is registered.

```
function removeMe() 
{
   // this refers to the item that invoked removeMe()
   var removeList = document.getElementById("taskList");
   removeList.removeChild(this.parentNode.parentNode);

}
```

Also, this is how you properly [add event listeners](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_eventlistener.asp)

```
spanBox.addEventListener("click", removeMe);
```

[Here is a working jsfiddle for you](https://jsfiddle.net/0pcrwjyd/)

Comment: I get the following error when using what you suggested.
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'

Comment: The error is caused by 'this' not being a child node of removeList. Can you provide the exact html structure? Potentially you need to call this.parentNode or similar.

Comment: For some reason, I'm only able to get one picture to show. I have switched the picture to the family tree.

Comment: I get the following error when I try the updated way.

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of undefined ... Also I tried removeList.removeChild(this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209029/discussion-between-frank-johnson-and-eriks-klotins).